# Great backstabbing (high damage) weapon?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I need a high damaging weapon to punish other plays on PvP with. I know there's that amazing greatsword that looks semi-deformed. Does anyone know what that is called?

Comment: Is this SotFS? Or the Original?

Comment: @Ben I would say both SotFS and the original game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this has been patched in the new SotFS edition, but in the original, you could simply not pass up the [Dagger](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Dagger). This weapon's crit was *through the roof*.

Following this, most DEX based weapons (like [daggers](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Daggers) and [rapiers](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Piercing+Swords)) also have a high AR, which contributes highly to crit damage.

As for "semi-deformed greatsword", it all depends on your definition of "semi-deformed". IMO that could be the [Black Dragon Greatsword](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Black+Dragon+Greatsword), the [Loyce Greatwsord](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Charred+Loyce+Greatsword) and the [Charred Loyce Greatsword](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Loyce+Greatsword), which all have a fairly high AR.

If you use an [AR Calculator](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Weapon+AR+and+Scaling+Calculator) you'll be able to find the best fit for you, because a weapon's AR is based off your stats.

Comment: The only difference in the SotFS edition is the enemy and item placement and some other area changes like many more stone statues (and that only on the PS4, XOne and DX11). There are no changes in balancing, because it's otherwise identical to the original with the latest patch and DLC, as far as I know. Can you somewhere in game see how high the critical damage of a weapon is? Especially in the beginning the dagger is really good.

Comment: @Kodama Thanks, I think it was the Black Dragon Greatsword. I have beaten the original Dark Souls 2 and SotFS and looking for some after-game PvP.